# ARM Assembly for development board

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, arm

I'm currently messing around with an LPC 2378 which has an application board attached. On the fan there are several components, 2 of which are a fan and a heater.

If bits 6 and 7 of port 4 are connected to the fan (motor controller), the following code will turn on the fan:

```
  FanOn
  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Push r0, r5 and LR
  LDR R5, =FIO4PIN            ; Address of FIO4PIN
  LDR r0, [r5]                ; Read current Port4
  ORR r0, r0, #0x80
  STR r0, [r5]                ; Output
  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14                 ; Put link register back into PC
```

How can I rewrite this block of code to turn on a heater connected to bit 5 of port 4, (Setting the bit to 1 will turn it on, setting it to 0 will turn it off).

Edit after answered question:

```
;==============================================================================
; Turn Heater On
;==============================================================================
heaterOn
  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Push r0, r5 and LR
  LDR R5, =FIO4PIN            ; Address of FIO4PIN
  LDR r0, [r5]                ; Read current Port4
  ORR r0, r0, #0x20
  STR r0, [r5]                ; Output
  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14                 ; Put link register back into PC     
;==============================================================================
; Turn The Heater Off
;==============================================================================        
heaterOff
  STMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Push r0, r5 and LR
  LDR R5, =FIO4PIN            ; Address of FIO4PIN
  LDR r0, [r5]                ; Read current Port4
  AND r0, r0, #0xDF
  STR r0, [r5]                ; Output
  LDMFD r13!,{r0,r5,r14}      ; Pop r0, r5 and LR
  mov pc, r14                 ; Put link register back into PC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I understand the code, the fan is connected only to bit 7 (if bits are numerated from 0).

The following line is responsible for turning the fan-bit on:

```
ORR r0, r0, #0x80
```

You are setting all the bits that are 1 in the "mask" to 1. Since the mask is `0x80`, that is `1000 0000` in binary, it only turns on bit 7.

Now, if you need to turn on the heater instead of the fan, and you have to set bit 5 instead of 7 (on the same port), you only need to change the mask in that line. New mask should be `0010 0000` binary, that is `0x20` in hexa, so the new code should be:

```
ORR r0, r0, #0x20
```

Also, if you want to turn the heater off at some point later, you do it by unsetting only bit 5, by anding with a mask that has 1s everywhere except on bit 5. If the mnemonic for bitwise and is `BIC`, the line would be:

```
BIC r0, r0, 0xDF
```

Now, I have not done any assembly in months but if I am not very mistaken, the code snippet you gave is actually a subroutine. You would call it from you main functionality with something like `call` to the `FanOn` address. And, to me, it seems that the subroutine is nice in a way that it preserves all the registers it uses, e.g. it pushes them to a stack in the first line and recovers them in the end.

So, to re-use the code, you could just write a new subroutine for turning the heater on, and one for turning each thing off if you want, and only change the label/subroutine name for each one, e.g. `FanOff`, `HeaterOn`...

Since all of them preserve all the registers, you can use them sequentially without worries.

Comment: I believe it's BIC (although it could be AND), so BIC r0, r0, 0xDF? I don't want to look as if i'm straying off from the original question. As it was 'how to reuse the code', would I need to use a different register if both the fan and the heater are turned off sequentially?

Comment: @user1080390 I added answers to your questions from the comments. You should edit that in to the question, expanding it, won't hurt anybody. I don't think you need to put the answer programme code in the question, but that's only my subjective opinion :D

Answer (score 1):

The `ORR` instruction turns ON a bit, the `#0x80` constant determines the bit(s) (in this case, only bit 7 is turned on).  To turn OFF the bit, you will need an AND instruction and compute the appropriate mask (e.g., to turn OFF bit 7, you would AND with constant #0x7F). The appropriate constants for bit 5 are `#0x20` and `#0xDF`.